# Adding records to crossfilter dosen't update the dc.js lineChart group

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, dc.js

I am using dc.js and crossfilter in my application.
In my code, I listen for event when data is coming (for example from websocket) and add the data to my crossfilter instance and then I call dc.redrawAll();

I have seen that the dc lineChart dosen't update it's grouping values.

```
var instance = crossfilter();

function onData(data) {
  instance.add(data);

  // -- code to update the x/y axis domains

  dc.redrawAll();
}

function drawLineChart() {
  var dimension = instance.dimension(function(){ .. });

  // => WHEN DATA IS ADDED (onData)
  // THE GROUPING DOSEN'T UPDATE
  var grouping = dimension.group().reduceCount();

  // initializing the line chart
  var lineChart = dc.lineChart() ....;

  lineChart.dimension(dimension).group(grouping);
}
```

What should I do to update the grouping?

Answer (score 5):

dimension and group should be automatically updated. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/yHmkc/1/

Where the data added and chart updated 1 sec later

```
setTimeout(function () {
    cf.add([{
        "key": "KEY-6",
        "state": "MD",
        "topics": ["Science"],
        "date": new Date("10/09/2012")
    }]);
    dc.redrawAll();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what your `data` is, but I assume that it's a single object rather than an array of data objects. You need to pass an array. If you pass just a single data object it seems to silently fail as you observed.

```
instance.add([data]); // `[data]` instead of `data`
```

Comment: My data is an array.

Comment: Strange.. I ran into the same issue as you and that turned out to be the cause for me. But now that I think about it, when I tried to add my data wrapped in an array, that just exposed an issue that was silently failing before. The problem was the value accessor for the dimension was returning undefined. I haven't tried to add a single object since I fixed it so maybe adding single items is OK. Definitely check your value accessor for the dimension to see if you have any undefined floating around.